# Join decision trees models into one decision tree

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree

I have five decision trees for five datasets. I want to combine them all into one decision tree.
I believe It is something similar to bagging technique. It would be great if experts post few links that are helpful. I am not looking to retrain the datasets, just combining the trees. Help is appreciated. TIA :)

Comment: Try to check out [Merging Decision Trees: A Case Study In Predicting Student Performance](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271214468_Merging_Decision_Trees_A_Case_Study_In_Predicting_Student_Performance) and some of the references

Comment: Or [A Survey of Merging Decision Trees Data Mining Approaches](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271213587_A_Survey_of_Merging_Decision_Trees_Data_Mining_Approaches)